# Out of memory when I create a json object list.toJSONString()

Tags: sql, json, jsp

hello java web gurus please i need your to help me resolve this out of memory exception when i create list.toJSONString in the code below.

```
String query1 = "select * from booking where id='"+ids+"'";

rs = stmt.executeQuery(query1);

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
while(rs.next())
{
    
    String passengerName = rs.getString("passengerName");
    String passengerPhone = rs.getString("passengerPhone");
    String emergencyPhone = rs.getString("emergencyPhone");
    String trip = rs.getString("trip");
    String destination = rs.getString("destination");
    String seatNumber = rs.getString("seatNumber");
    String cad = rs.getString("idNumber");
    obj.put("passengerName", passengerName);
    obj.put("passengerPhone", passengerPhone);
    obj.put("emergencyPhone", emergencyPhone);
    obj.put("trip", trip);
    obj.put("destination", destination);
    obj.put("seatNumber", seatNumber);
    obj.put("cad", cad);
    list.add(obj);
}

out.print(list.toJSONString());
out.flush();
```

this code run for some time and crush with the error message below

23-Jul-2022 11:44:00.326 SEVERE [http-nio-81-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/ctracker] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [calData.jsp] at line [282]

and this is the line 282

```
out.print(list.toJSONString());
```

and lastly the tomcat error message

Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: please help me dear java full stack developers

Comment: Try selecting 5 records first, to make sure your logic works.   Seems like you are trying to load so many records, the string exceeds the memory size.

Comment: not that it doesn't work it works but stops at certain point

Comment: As `ids` what you are providing and as a result how many result do you expect(or you got when you query directly from database)?

Comment: ids is a variable that stores the id of the data in the databese

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java expert but appearently your data fills heap space before you flush out memory.

Instead combining all the output of database result just one time, print out on every iteration or get a bigger memory:

```
String query1 = "select * from booking where id='"+ids+"'";

rs = stmt.executeQuery(query1);

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
while(rs.next())
{
    
    String passengerName = rs.getString("passengerName");
    String passengerPhone = rs.getString("passengerPhone");
    String emergencyPhone = rs.getString("emergencyPhone");
    String trip = rs.getString("trip");
    String destination = rs.getString("destination");
    String seatNumber = rs.getString("seatNumber");
    String cad = rs.getString("idNumber");
    obj.put("passengerName", passengerName);
    obj.put("passengerPhone", passengerPhone);
    obj.put("emergencyPhone", emergencyPhone);
    obj.put("trip", trip);
    obj.put("destination", destination);
    obj.put("seatNumber", seatNumber);
    obj.put("cad", cad);
    list.add(obj);

    out.print(list.toJSONString());
    out.flush();
}
```

Comment: okay so i should flush the memory first or?